# Agreggating the masses and coordinates of a number of points to calculate their gravitational pull on an object in a single step

Tags: gravity, mass

I have $n$ points, each of these have a set of coordinates and a mass; what I want to do is calculate the resultant force they induce on an object whose coordinates I also know.

I can do that simply by calculating the separate force for each of the points and adding them together, but this is a bit too slow for my purposes, as calculating their effect on each other takes $n^2$ steps.

So what I wanted to know is whether it is possible to somehow aggregate their masses and coordinates and then treat that accumulated value as a single object which I can use to calculate the gravitational pull. I was thinking of calculating the center of mass but that just doesn't output correct results (as it shouldn't). For example, if I have the points in the edges of a square, the force they induce on an object in the middle of the square is zero, but if I get their center of mass, the object is lying right in it so the force would be infinite.

Is there any other method of accumulation I could use to get the desired result?

Comment: This seems more suited for [SciComp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: So you want to know the force not just at one time but at many times as the system evolves? I think this is a hard problem even for [$n=3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)

Comment: Here this link might be helpful. It's from wikipedia.org, which is a nice reference site. [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation#Calculation_optimizations)

Comment: See, the tree method is just what I had in mind. The problem is that the center of mass doesn't actually give the correct results.